# Why android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost is not rendered in Android XML Graphical Layout?

Tags: android, render, android-xml, fragment-tab-host, graphical-layout-editor

## **`Problem`**

**`android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost`** is not displayed in Graphical Layout of Android XML.

## **`Error Image`**

[image: FragmentTabHost Render Error Image]

## **`XML Code Snippets`**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp" >

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

### **`Request/Conclusion`**

If any **solution** for this problem then please share.
If I need to change in **eclipse** then also give suggestion. 
Thank you.